# Rake spec fails - Name error, Load error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

new to rspec, need to work on a test, when I run rake spec I get these errors, searched thru a bunch of old similar issues but nothing is working. not sure what to do...please help.

ruby -v 2.1.2
rails -v 4.1.4

http://pastebin.com/VJUh0Hhg

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have the the following file? `/Users/jessep/work/noterizer/spec/config/environment`

Comment: no, but I have /Users/jessep/work/noterizer/config/environments

Comment: Would be great if you put the content of `/Users/jessep/work/noterizer/spec/helpers/notes_helper_spec.rb` but see my answer and give a try

Answer (score 0):

I guess the file located at `/Users/jessep/work/noterizer/spec/helpers/notes_helper_spec.rb` have an issue in the line 2

probably it looks like: 
`require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)`

to fix the issue just add `../` so should look like:
`require File.expand_path("../../../config/environment", __FILE__)`

Comment: tried adding ../ to notes_helper_spec.rb and got same error - latest here -   [link] (http://pastebin.com/ZBigqNYA) and here is the notes_helper_spec.rb - [link] (http://pastebin.com/jTXgFxFM)

Comment: can you share the file?

Comment: are you having the exactly same log?